# Derivative definition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a differentiable function in $x_0$. Calculate the following $\lim$:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+2h)-f(x_0-h)}{5h}$$

since we know from theory that $f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$, then

I said that $x_0-h=t$ and $x_0+2h=t+3h$ where $3h=k$ so $$\frac{3}{5}\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(t+k)-f(t)}{k}=\frac{3}{5}f'(t)=\frac{3}{5}f'(x_0-h)$$

Comment: You should be careful, since your $t$ also depends on $h$ which affects $k$, so it's not a constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\dfrac{f(x_0 + 2h) - f(x_0 - h)}{5h} = \dfrac{2}{5}\dfrac{f(x_0 + 2h) - f(x_0)}{2h} + \frac{1}{5}\dfrac{f(x_0 - h) - f(x_0)}{-h}
$$

Now take the limit as $h \to 0$.